# Suite Class not calling @BeforeClass & @AfterClass

Tags: maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit, surefire

I have a suite of test cases. I want @BeforeClass & @AfterClass to be called before and after test case execution respectively. When I run the suite class using JUnit it calls the methods correctly, ie setUp() will be called prior to testcases and tearDown() will be called after testcases are completed.But when I execute the maven to execute the testcases and generate report using surefire its not calling setUp() & tearDown()

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
@SuiteClasses({test1.class, test2.class})
public class SuiteClass{
    public static WebDriver driver;
    public static String baseUrl;
    public static StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUp() throws Exception {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        baseUrl = "http://localhost:7070/myproject/";
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDown() throws Exception {
        driver.quit();
        String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
        if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
            fail(verificationErrorString);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see how Surefire would even be able to identify your test class unless it has a `@test` annotation in it.

Comment: @djangofan, Thanks, you are correct, surefire is not including the suiteclass. Is there a way to include the suite class to surefire?

Comment: Surefire scans for it automatically in your `src/test/java` folder.  So, if you don't have classes in there than contain the Test annotation, it make sense that Surefire wouldn't find them.

Comment: I have all the classes in src/test/java. Do you mean that the suiteclass should contain @test annotation for surefire to locate it?

Comment: Ahh... you got me on that one.  Yeah, I would guess that Surefire doesn't know how to scan for that @SuiteClasses annotation.   I can't answer any further without more specific information.

Comment: @djangofan, I found the solution, please see my post below. Your help is much appreciated, Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found the solution :) Sharing it for others in need

**Suite class**

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
@SuiteClasses({test1.class, test2.class})
public class SuiteClass{
    public static WebDriver driver;
    public static String baseUrl;
    public static StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUp() throws Exception {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        baseUrl = "http://localhost:7070/myproject/";
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDown() throws Exception {
        driver.quit();
        String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
        if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
            fail(verificationErrorString);
        }
    }
}
```

**Entry in pom.xml for report generation**

```
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <outputName>TestReport</outputName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

**Specify Maven Goal to execute SuiteClass**

```
site -Dtest=com.test.testcase.SuiteClass
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
@SuiteClasses({test1.class, test2.class})
public class SuiteClass{
    public static WebDriver driver;
    public static String baseUrl;
    public static StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUp() throws Exception {

    public static WebDriver driver;
    public static String baseUrl;
    public static StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDown() throws Exception {
        driver.quit();
        String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
        if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
            fail(verificationErrorString);
        }
    }
}
```

Try Above u know what u did wrong...

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. This won't work, the problem is that surefire is ignoring the suiteclass as it don't have @test annotation.

Answer (score 0):

It is not because TestSuite does not have any annotation. Reason why surefire is not picking your suite is surefire only picks classes with the following naming conventions when looking for tests to run:

1.Test*

2.*Test

3.*TestCase.

If you update the name of your suite following above convention, it will work just fine.